Locally cohomologically trivial set is interior of its closure?
The question is a part of Kashiwara's sheaves on manifolds exercise3.4:
Let $X$ be a $C^{0}-$manifold. We shall say that a locally closed subset $\Omega$ is locally cohomologically trivial in $X$ (l.c.t for short) if for any $x \in \overline{\Omega} \backslash \Omega$, one has:
$\begin{align*} (R\Gamma_{\overline{\Omega}}(A_{X}))_{x} = 0 \end{align*}$, $\begin{align*} (R\Gamma_{\Omega}(A_{X}))_{x} \cong A \end{align*}$, where $A$ is a unital comutative ring and $A_{X}$ is the constant sheaf. Prove that if $\Omega$ is l.c.t in $X$ then $\Omega =$Int$(\overline{\Omega})$.
(The definition of $\Gamma_{\Omega}$ can be seen in  What are the stalks of $\Gamma_Z(F)$ for a locally closed subset $Z$ and a flabby sheaf $F$, and $R\Gamma_{\Omega}$ is its right derived functor.)
I can check that Int$(\overline{\Omega})$ $\subset \Omega$. In fact, for $x \in $ Int$(\overline{\Omega})$ but not in $\Omega$ we have:
$\begin{align*} H^{j}(R\Gamma_{\overline{\Omega}}(A_{X}))_{x} = \lim_{\overrightarrow{x \in U}} H^{j}(R\Gamma(U;R\Gamma_{\overline{\Omega}}(A_{X})) =  \lim_{\overrightarrow{x \in U}} H^{j}(R\Gamma_{\overline{\Omega} \cap U}(U;A_{X})) = \\ \lim_{\overrightarrow{x \in U}} H^{j}(R\Gamma_{ U}(U;A_{X})) = \lim_{\overrightarrow{x \in U}} H^{j}( R\Gamma(U;A_{X})) \end{align*}$
Hence $R\Gamma_{\overline{\Omega}}(A_{X}))_{x} \cong A$ which contradicts the conditions. But I have no idea to check $\Omega$ $\subset$ Int$(\overline{\Omega})$. Can anyone give me some help?
